# how to create a Forward proxy to view websites using Node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am trying to setup a node.js proxy server to allow me to send requests from firefox to the node.js server to view external websites

Generally i would like to set firefox settings to point to a working node proxy server to view external websites.

I need to see code for a working example the simpler the better

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mwotton/6077238#comment-874975). It has some code samples

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. Currently this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [throttle-proxy](https://npmjs.org/package/throttle-proxy) npm package (throttling is optional).